# How to send album art through bluetooth to third party device?

Tags: android, bluetooth, metadata, android-mediaplayer

When using My Streaming mediaplayer app on an Android device to play over bluetooth, third-party devices don't receive metadata album art ? How to do that ?

Comment: Is this your app that you are creating?

Comment: nope, created a streaming music player.

Comment: you need to be alot more specific. Display code showing what you are currently doing that isn't giving you the desired results